# Excel: Select a date that is in between 2 dates

Tags: excel

I am looking to create an excel formula that will retrieve the "Date Before" and the "Date After" a specific Date from a list. For example:

The date of my report is in cell S13 (January 14th, 2023), and I am looking to pull the date right before it and right after from the choices in column Q. In this example, the date right before is cell Q13 (Jan 5, 2023) and the date right after is cell Q14 (Feb 5, 2023). How can I create an automated formula to pull this? Thank you!

[screenshot of workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDMRb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on cell `D2` to obtain both values:

```
=LET(rng, A2:A20, refDate, C2, 
  TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER(rng, (rng<>"") 
  * ((rng = MAXIFS(rng, rng,"<"&refDate)) 
    + (rng = MINIFS(rng, rng,">"&refDate)))))))
```

Here is the result:

[image: sample excel file]

**Notes**:

1. The OR-condition in `FILTER` function is stablished by addition of two logical conditions: `A + B` in the second input argument and AND-condition by multiplication, i.e. `A*B`.
2. To transpose an array column you can use also `TOROW`.
3. The `LET` function is used to simplify the formula maintenance, so we define `rng` and `refDate` any change to those variables you can change only one time in the formula
4. `(rng <>"")` is added to exclude empty rows

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS`....

Date Before formula:

```
=MAXIFS($A:$A,$A:$A,"<="&$C5)
```

Date After formula:

```
=MINIFS($A:$A,$A:$A,">="&$C5)
```

Not sure how you want to treat <>=, so remove the = sign if desired.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=INDEX(Q10:Q28,MATCH(0,Q10:Q28-$S$13,1))
```

and

```
=INDEX(Q10:Q28,MATCH(0,Q10:Q28-$S$13,1)+1)
```

entered as array formulas (ctrl+shift+ENTER).